# Could not determine java version from '16.0.2'

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm using java 7 and gradle trying to make a minecraft java 1.7.2 mod
downloaded files from https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.2.html
and get this error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '16.0.2'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '16.0.2'.
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.<init>(Jvm.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.create(Jvm.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current(Jvm.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.configuration.CurrentProcess.<init>(CurrentProcess.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.canUseCurrentProcess(BuildActionsFactory.java:151)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActionsFactory.java:131)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.createAction(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:196)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:55)
```

can some one help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, you're using jdk 16, and not jdk 7. Gradle for Minecraft Forge 1.7.2 doesn't support jdk 16. Add jdk 7 to your project and remove jdk 16 and your problem should be solved.